# Why root directory node does not exist while nodes under root directory exist in zookeeper instance?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am running a zookeeper instance aka IA in standalone mode, trying to upgrade to quorum mode, then I prepared another 2 zookeeper instances(IB and IC) with empty snapshot directory, first modified zoo.cfg properly in 3 instances, and created myid respectively, restart the standalone instance IA first, then start the other 2.

What happened to IB and IC is, they have the data, but the root directory is not there:

Both IB and IC:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 14] ls /
Node does not exist: /
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 15] ls /zookeeper
[quota]
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 16]
```

besides, there is data loss in IB:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 16] get /demo/version

cZxid = 0x30000006c
ctime = Thu Dec 22 17:49:13 CST 2016
mZxid = 0x30000006c
mtime = Thu Dec 22 17:49:13 CST 2016
pZxid = 0x6003792a0
cversion = 12764622
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 0
numChildren = 135794
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 17]
```

IA looks like:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 10] get /demo/version

cZxid = 0x30000006c
ctime = Thu Dec 22 17:49:13 CST 2016
mZxid = 0x30000006c
mtime = Thu Dec 22 17:49:13 CST 2016
pZxid = 0x6003792a0
cversion = 12312921
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 0
numChildren = 587495
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 11]
```

IC looks like:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 10] get /demo/version

cZxid = 0x30000006c
ctime = Thu Dec 22 17:49:13 CST 2016
mZxid = 0x30000006c
mtime = Thu Dec 22 17:49:13 CST 2016
pZxid = 0x6003792a0
cversion = 12312921
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x0
dataLength = 0
numChildren = 587495
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 11]
```

btw, the status are just fine:

IA:

```
[shell@kernel /data/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin]# ./zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /data/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: follower
```

IB:

```
[shell@kernel /data/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin]# ./zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /data/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: follower
```

IC:

```
[shell@kernel /data/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin]# ./zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /data/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: leader
```

As shown above, the version is

> 3.4.8

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by changing the `initLimit` and `syncLimit` to `100` and `50` respectively, `tickTime` remains to `2000`, then migrate from standalone mode to quorum mode, wait a moment, everything went fine then.